# Положение курсора при старте приложения PyQt5 Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlineedit, курсор

При старте приложения курсор автоматически стоит в том поле для ввода текста, которое находится выше и левее остальных. Как в данном примере мне сделать так, чтобы при запуске программы курсор сразу находился в нижнем QLineEdit?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout,  QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QApplication


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.layout_main_window = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout_main_window)

        self.line_edit_1 = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_2 = QLineEdit()

        self.layout_main_window.addWidget(self.line_edit_1)
        self.layout_main_window.addWidget(self.line_edit_2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я пробовал использовать `self.line_edit_2.setCurcor(QCursor())`, но ничего не происходит.

Comment: `self.line_edit_2.setFocus();`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение подсказано в комментариях:
`self.line_edit_2.setFocus()`